# Spring MVC - how to edit data from database in JSP table using DAO+Service

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I got editable table created in jsp, which is displaying whole table from database, and next to last column I got "edit" button which updates particular row. The problem is that after click "edit" edited rows dont want to be updated and any of errors appears in console. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/employeelist.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editOrDeleteEmployee(Model model, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, @RequestParam String editEmployee) throws SQLException{

        setAppContext();        

        clinicService.updateEmployee(employee, "2");

        List<Employee> employees = clinicService.getAllEmployees(); 
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);

        ModelAndView mstaff = new ModelAndView("EmployeeList");
        return mstaff;

    }
```

DAO:

```
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee, String id) {
    String query = "update virtualclinic.employee SET name=?, lastname=?, gender=?,"
            + "position=?, salary=?, phonenumner=?, address=? WHERE idemployee=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
        ps.setString(2, employee.getLastName());
        ps.setString(3, employee.getGender());
        ps.setString(4, employee.getPosition());
        ps.setString(5, employee.getSalary());
        ps.setString(5, employee.getPhoneNumber());
        ps.setString(6, employee.getAddress());
        ps.setString(7, employee.getId());

        id = employee.getId();

        int out = ps.executeUpdate();



    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Service:

```
public void updateEmployee(Employee employee, String id) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    employeeDAO = ctx.getBean("employeeDAO", EmployeeDAOImpl.class);

    employee.setName(employee.getName());
    employee.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
    employee.setGender(employee.getGender());
    employee.setPosition(employee.getPosition());
    employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
    employee.setPhoneNumber(employee.getPhoneNumber());
    employee.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
    employee.setId(employee.getId());

    id = employee.getId();

    employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee, id);

}
```

JSP file:

```
 <c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr style="font-size: 10">
                <td>${employee.id}</td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.name}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.lastName}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.gender}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.position}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.salary}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.phoneNumber}</div></td>
                <td><div contentEditable='true'>${employee.address}</div></td>
                <td><form action="/VirtualClinic/employeelist.html?editEmployee=${employee.id}"  method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Edit"/></form></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are receiving the `employee` object as well employee ID in controller?

Comment: I'm sure that it isn't null, in POST method I add system.out.prinln(employee) and in console something is displaying, other DAO methods works fine, so I think that this object is received